# C# Entity Framework Primary Key Violation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting data from an external API and want to save it in SQL Server with the Entity Framework. The data I am getting is order information. The data is roughly laid out like this:

Order:

- Order ID
- Customer
- Shipping Address
- Items

Customer:

- Customer ID
- Customer Details

The problem is that any customer can place more than one order. My entity framework is based around the Order information. So if a customer places more than one order, I get a primary key violation because the customer is already in the database even though the order is not.

For reference: I usually add orders like so: `orderContext.Orders.Add(order);`

Since every order contains the customer data, I can not add an order without "adding" a customer. Even if I were to check for an existing customer, I would still have to add the record to the Orders table, which would still trigger the problem. Is there any way to tell EF to add or update each "child" class?

The example here is more simplistic than the actual data. There are several other dependencies like this, such that even if I were to switch to using the Customer class as the basis for the EF, it would still have this problem.

Comment: You have the customer id. Why can't you use that to match to a previous instance of the customer; making necessary updates?

Comment: What's the structure of your database? Does it have an Orders table and Customers table? Show your entities and an example API response being casted and saved to SQL server (Code).

Comment: My guess is that you are assigning a disconnected Customer to your order.  When the order is inserted EF thinks it's a new customer (because it's disconnected) and tries to insert another one with the same ID.  The solution, if this is the case, is to use the CustomerID instead of the navigation property, or to attach the customer to the context as an unmodified entry.

Comment: `Add` also marks related entities as `Added` when they're not yet attached to the context.

Answer (score 0):

Change your tables like this:

add CustomerID to your `Order` table, this is because everyone `Order` has just **one** `Customer` and every `Customer` has **many or zero** `Order`

Order(OrderID,CustomerID,ShippingAddress)

Customer(CustomerID,...)